# Redundant values in dataframe to be used as a key and another column as a value

Tags: python

I got a dataframe like

```
name  count  title
a       1      c1
a       2      c2
a       3      b1
b       4      f1
b       5      f2
c       6      g1
```

I want to transfer it to a dict with `name` as key and `title` as value.

I expect the output to be like

```
{a: [c1, c2, b1], b: [f1, f2], c: [g1]}
```

I tried this:

```
sites = {} 
features = []       
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    sites[row["name"]] = features.append(row["title"])
```

and got a dictionary with `None` values as

```
{a: None, b: None, c: None}
```

Why do I get `None` and how can I do this correctly?

---

I also tried this:

```
your_dict = df.groupby(["Name"])["title"].apply(list).to_dict().get("Name")
```

and also got `None` value.

Comment: Did you try iterating over the rows in the dataframe and appending the value of the "title" column to a list in the dictionary using the value of the "Name" column as key?

Comment: yes and it gives me a dict with none value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_dict = df.groupby(["name"])["title"].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: it gives me None

Comment: @AshrafKhaled adjusted my answer, try this one

Comment: if i want to check in this dict if any key contains those 3 things [ c1 , c2 , b1] print it , what can I do ?

Comment: ['c1', 'c2', 'b1'] in your_dict.values()

Comment: even if the list conatins others ? , I need it as a must

Comment: as an example :

if key1 : [ a , b ,c ,d ,e ]
and key 2 : [ a , b ,e]

i need to print key 1 as it contains all of [ a, b ,c] together  and not key 2

Answer (score 0):

The `append` method appends a value to a list by modifying it. It does not return anything (more specifically, it returns `None`).

Therefore, by writing

> ```
> sites[row["name"]] = features.append(row["title"])
> ```

you insert `None` values into the dictionary.

Instead, you need to use

```
sites[row["name"]].append(row["title"])
```

For this to work you need to ensure that the list exists when you try to append to it for the first time. An easy way to do this is to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

sites = defaultdict(list)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sites[row["name"]].append(row["title"])
```